# solving latency in mysql update queries

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

so I have written a query as follows:

```
UPDATE 
table1 latest, table2 previous
SET latest.col1 = previous.col1
WHERE latest.col2 = previous.col2 and previous.col1 is not null;
```

which copies the value of col2, from table2 to table 1 wherever the value of col1, matches. However due to the context, there can be no primary/foreign key constraints involve and col2 doesn't contain nulls but col1 does( in both tables)..

however this query takes several minutes to execute! is there a way to speeded it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding indexes to both table. Created indexes for the common column on which the tables were being joined. Wherever lookups are performed, either through joins, the columns being joined/lookedup should have indexes

Comment: It's good to hear that you found the cause of your problem.  You could make your answer more helpful for future readers by explaining *how* you diagnosed it, and in particular, which evidence will identify this problem when it's seen elsewhere.